# Blogger (Python) API: How do I retrieve a post by post ID?

Tags: python, blogger, gdata

Having previously obtained a post ID from a call to `gdata.blogger.client.add_post()`...

```
post = client.add_post(...)
post_id = post.get_post_id()
```

...how do I use that post id to retrieve the post in the future?  I thought maybe `gdata.blogger.client.Query` would be the way to go, but this doesn't support post id as a query term.  The example code distributed with the Python `gdata` module doesn't have an example of this use case, and after poking around `gdata.blogger.client.*` for a while I'm not making much progress.

I could obviously iterate through all the posts in the blog until  find the one with the corresponding id, but that would be a terrible, terrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue my theme of answering my own questions...

After lots of fiddling, it looks like this is one solution. Given:

- client -- a gdata.blogger.client.BloggerClient instance, and
- blog -- a gdata.blogger.data.Blog instance
- post_id -- a post id as returned by gdata.blogger.data.BlogPost.get_post_id

You can do this:

```
post = client.get_feed(
            blog.get_post_link().href + '/%s' % post_id,
            auth_token=client.auth_token,
            desired_class=gdata.blogger.data.BlogPost)
```